# How to document a 'parameter-list like' array in JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, arrays, jsdoc, jsdoc3, jsdoc2md

It is common in JavaScript to work with arrays that are essentially argument lists: a small fixed length, and known types for each position. This is especially true for ECMAScript 6, which introduced features like the [rest operator,](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and [iterator protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#The_iterator_protocol).

I'd like to document a function that returns an iterator object, for iterating over key/value pairs. Ideally, I'd like to be specific in its type. Is it possible to do this with (any) JSDoc? Here's my latest attempt, but I don't know if it's valid:

```
/**
 * @returns { { next: function(): {done: boolean, value: [string, *]} } }
 */
```

[`jsdoc-to-markdown`](https://github.com/jsdoc2md/jsdoc-to-markdown) complains about the syntax, but this might be on their end, not JSDoc 3. If so, I'll send them a bug report later.

**Edit:** Here is an example object that might be returned:

```
{
    next: function () {
        return {
            done: false,
            value: ['answer', 42]
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you maybe post a sample object that this is supposed to return?

Comment: @SGD: I added an example to the question.

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot type array elements individually, at least there is nothing which even remotely indicates that this is possible. I might be missing something of course.

Comment: As far as I know, it should be *[]